# How to fetch a memory location in C++ without waiting for its retrieval?

Tags: c++, caching, optimization, compiler-optimization, latency

Suppose we want to fetch a value from an array.

In some cases, we know that the data is in `data[i]`.

In other cases, we need to move the index by some offset: `i += offset[i]`

```
i = ....

FETCH data[i];         // The result could be here if the offset_shifts is 0 
                       // Or if i is very small (data[i] is in the same cache line & page)

i += offset_shifts[i];     // LLC cache miss (and most probably a TLB miss)

result = data[i];       // LLC cache miss (and most probably a TLB miss), 
                        // unless it is obtained by an earlier FETCH
```

The benefit that I expect from this trick is that if  `offset_shifts[i]` is small, then it means that there will be no TLB & LLC cache misses, so that those lookups can be done with the overhead of ONE memory lookup (instead of two)

How can I fetch the value of `data[i]` **at the same time** that `offset_shifts[i]` is being fetched from memory? In other words, what is the proper way to implement such a "non-blocking fetch" in C++?

Comment: It seems like you are making too many bold assumptions out of thin air. Are you really sure that you've optimized your code to the extent that in order to squeeze extra bits of performance you need to figure out potential cache miss patters?

Comment: @user7860670 Yes, this is the bottleneck. Merely looking up ```data[i]``` takes roughly 35 ns and adding the ```offset_shifts[i]``` lookups increases the entire query processing latency to ```60ns```. The other overheads of the code are all on cache-resident data and hence negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In portable C++, I'd solve it as follows:

```
result = data[i]; // Unconditional!
auto offset = offset_shifts[i];
if (offset)
   result = data[i+offset];
```

The rationale is that `result` is likely just a register, so `result = data[i];` is effectively just a read. This will start the read, but not block the CPU pipeline for the next operation. `offset_shifts[i]` is effectively retrieved in parallel with the previous operation. (The optimizer may even swap the two operations - it knows more about CPU's than I do). If the branch is taken, you get the intended cache effect. If not taken, the operation is as effective as it can be.

Comment: You can't reason like that if using the optimiser (which is the only time you'd care about this level of performance tuning).  The compiler's free to reorder the code, or observe that the `data[i]` read may be overwritten when `offset` is true and effectively create it's own "else" branch for that scenario.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: The compiler is indeed free to do that. But note that the compiler has no idea how likely the branch is. The CPU's branch predictor on the other hand will know that, and the compiler knows that the branch predictor will know. Profile-Guided Optimization may help even more.

Comment: If you're basically saying "we can probably trust the CPU to work this stuff out so it doesn't really matter what I've written or whether my reasoning for expecting it to help is right", why bother showing any code?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: No, that's not how it works. Not at all. We don't "trust" the CPU to "work it out". We trust the CPU to predict the branch. And we trust the compiler to know what a branch predictor does. That's why I deliberately wrote that branch, even though branches have a reputation for being expensive. We also trust the scheduler to have the load of `data[i]` run in parallel with the branch, making it effectively free, because the scheduler knows how the CPU works.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ language standard doesn't provide support for this, but some compilers do.  For example, GCC provides [`__builtin_prefetch`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

```
Built-in Function: void __builtin_prefetch (const void *addr, ...)

This function is used to minimize cache-miss latency by moving data into a
cache before it is accessed. You can insert calls to __builtin_prefetch into
code for which you know addresses of data in memory that is likely to be
accessed soon. If the target supports them, data prefetch instructions are 
generated. If the prefetch is done early enough before the access then the
data will be in the cache by the time it is accessed.

The value of addr is the address of the memory to prefetch. There are two
optional arguments, rw and locality. The value of rw is a compile-time
constant one or zero; one means that the prefetch is preparing for a write to
the memory address and zero, the default, means that the prefetch is preparing
for a read. The value locality must be a compile-time constant integer between
zero and three. A value of zero means that the data has no temporal locality,
so it need not be left in the cache after the access. A value of three means
that the data has a high degree of temporal locality and should be left in all
levels of cache possible. Values of one and two mean, respectively, a low or
moderate degree of temporal locality. The default is three.

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    __builtin_prefetch (&a[i+j], 1, 1);
    __builtin_prefetch (&b[i+j], 0, 1);
    /* … */
  }

Data prefetch does not generate faults if addr is invalid, but the address
expression itself must be valid. For example, a prefetch of p->next does not
fault if p->next is not a valid address, but evaluation faults if p is not a
valid address.

If the target does not support data prefetch, the address expression is
evaluated if it includes side effects but no other code is generated and
GCC does not issue a warning.
```

I'd recommend taking some measurements afterwards to see if prefetching actually helps significantly - no point complicating your code with non-portable compiler features for nothing.

Comment: The example given here looks like a fixed-stride access pattern (`j` does not vary). IIRC, that's actually hardware-prefetched already on modern hardware.

Comment: @MSalters: fair point that prefetch is often done automatically and GCC's example may not be the most relevant these days, but the facilities still there as documented for whatever actually useful prefetching needs to be manually coordinated.